# How to get the SimpleKPI KPI Entries API to return data?

Tags: rest

I'm using the [SimpleKPI](https://simplekpi.com) [API](https://support.simplekpi.com/Developers) and I can get data on Users and KPIs but I get a 200 OK empty array response for KPI Entries.

I've confirmed that the user I'm making the API request as owns the KPI ID by calling the "Get all User's KPIs" API:

```
GET /api/users/{user_id}/kpis
```

I'm then using the KPI Id in the "Get all KPI entries" API:

```
GET /api/kpientries?userid={user_id}&kpiid={kpi_id}
```

Here are the Dev Guide references:

- Users: https://support.simplekpi.com/Developers/Users
- Users / KPIs: https://support.simplekpi.com/Developers/UsersKPIs
- KPIs: https://support.simplekpi.com/Developers/KPIs
- KPI Entries: https://support.simplekpi.com/Developers/KPIEntries

What am I missing to get the KPI Entries data to return the data I see in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is that the `dateFrom` and `dateTo` query string parameters are required even though the description says they are optional. Supplying both values will result in KPI entries being returned.

Here's the current description:

> **Get all KPI entries**
>
> The KPI entries are filtered based on the search query string. All the search criteria is optional and we will return a maximum of 500 entries per page. If the result set has the amount of rows you set &rows=100, it's your responsibility to check the next page to see if there are any more -- you do this by adding &page=2 to the query, then &page=3 and so on.
>
> `GET /api/kpientries?userid=123&kpiid=456&dateFrom=YYYY-MM-DD&dateTo=YYYY-MM-DD&rows=100&page=2`

Reference: https://support.simplekpi.com/Developers/KPIEntries